# Solve without matrix inversion.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I need to implement some numpy matrix operations but very frequently the code breaks because a matrix determinant tends to be $0$ and the inverse can not be calculated.
Is there a way to calculate the value of $e$ in the following equation assuming we know $T$ and $s$ and they are a MxM matrix and Mx1 vector, respectively.
$T=se^T-es^T$

PS: This has to do with fusing classifier predictions, and $\hat{T}=\hat{s}e^T-e\hat{s}^T$ will be a matrix that results after a singular value thresholding operation on a the mean matrix $T$ of the prediction scores. In order to recreate the fused prediction $\hat{s}$ i need to know $e$.

Comment: Depending on the problem you are solving you can maybe implement a regularizer. Which type is suitable can depend on what the purpose of the equation solving is.

Comment: @mathreadler How do you mean?

Comment: You can often make sure the matrix has an inverse by for example adding a small unit matrix $+\epsilon {\bf I}$ to make the determinant non 0. All the previous 0 eigenvalues will become $\epsilon$. That is called Tikhonov regularization and can often help make the equation systems well determined but maybe moving solution a bit as the existing non-0 eigenvalues will also get $+\epsilon$.

Comment: @mathreadler i tried that, but maybe my $\epsilon$ was too small. I will retry. Thanks

Comment: If it still does not work you can try solving the normal equations instead of directly inverting. If you want to solve $Ax = b$, instead try and solve $A^TAx = A^Tb$, the $A^TA$ often has nicer properties than $A$, but can sometimes be slower to solve.

Comment: You have more equations than variables. I would go for the least squares solution and if necessary the least norm solution.

Comment: @mathreadler The Tikhonov regularization worked, my epsilon was $10^4$ too smal before. Try to answer the question, i will accept it.